# In C++/CLI, Is it OK to use memcpy to copy managed arrays?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, unmanaged, memcpy, managed

I tried to use memcpy to combine two arrays,
Something like this:

```
array<short, 1>^ memTemp = gcnew array<short, 1>(8);
GCHandle handleOnData0 = GCHandle::Alloc(memTemp, GCHandleType::Pinned);
unsigned char* ptrOnData0 = (unsigned char*)handleOnData0.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();


array<short, 1>^ array1 = gcnew array<short, 1>{1, 2, 3, 4};
GCHandle handleOnData1 = GCHandle::Alloc(array1, GCHandleType::Pinned);
unsigned char* ptrOnData1 = (unsigned char*)handleOnData1.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();

array<short, 1>^ array2 = gcnew array<short, 1>{1, 2, 3, 4};
GCHandle handleOnData2 = GCHandle::Alloc(array2, GCHandleType::Pinned);
unsigned char* ptrOnData2 = (unsigned char*)handleOnData2.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();


memcpy(ptrOnData0, ptrOnData1, 8);
memcpy(ptrOnData0 + 8, ptrOnData2, 8);

handleOnData0.Free();
handleOnData1.Free();
handleOnData2.Free();
```

Is it OK to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `System::Array::Copy()`?

Comment: There are various degrees of wrong-ness, but yeah, this is pretty wrong.  Major beefs are that it is not exception-safe, you'll permanently leak when memcpy() fails and unwise enough to catch the AVE.  And GCHandle::Alloc() is unnecessarily inefficient, the `pin_ptr<>` class is far superior.  Gives you both very efficient pinning and thread-safety.  Still not good enough reasons to avoid Array::Copy() or even Marshal::Copy() here.